# Java 8 stream Map<String, List<String>> sum of values for each key

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I am not so familiar with Java 8 (still learning) and looking to see if I could find something equivalent of the below code using streams.

The below code mainly tries to get corresponding double value for each value in String and then sums it up. I could not find much help anywhere on this format. I am not sure if using streams would clean up the code or would make it messier.

```
// safe assumptions - String/List (Key/Value) cannot be null or empty
// inputMap --> Map<String, List<String>>

Map<String, Double> finalResult = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : inputMap.entrySet()) {
    Double score = 0.0;
    for (String current: entry.getValue()) {
        score += computeScore(current);
    }
    finalResult.put(entry.getKey(), score);
}

private Double computeScore(String a) { .. }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could also use the `forEach` method along with the stream API to yield the result you're seeking.

```
Map<String, Double> resultSet = new HashMap<>();
inputMap.forEach((k, v) -> resultSet.put(k, v.stream()
            .mapToDouble(s -> computeScore(s)).sum()));
```

`s -> computeScore(s)` could be changed to use a method reference i.e. `T::computeScore` where `T` is the name of the class containing `computeScore`.

Answer (score 11):

```
Map<String, Double> finalResult = inputMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue()
                      .stream()
                      .mapToDouble(str -> computeScore(str))
                      .sum()));
```

Above code iterates over the map and creates a new map with same keys & before putting the values, it first iterates over each value - which is a list, computes score via calling `computeScore()` over each list element and then sums the scores collected to be put in the value.

Comment: Please add some explanation to what you did and also format your code so that it becomes easy to read.

Comment: The code is already formatted. Can you please pinpoint in case I missed?

Comment: @PankajSinghal Formatted it a little bit, please add some explanation of what you did in the code.

Comment: Added the explanation

Answer (score 3):

How about this one:

```
Map<String, Double> finalResult = inputMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Double>(   // maps each key to a new
                                                                 // Entry<String, Double>
        entry.getKey(),                                          // the same key
        entry.getValue().stream()                             
            .mapToDouble(string -> computeScore(string)).sum())) // List<String> mapped to 
                                                                 // List<Double> and summed
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));  // collected by the same 
                                                                 // key and a newly 
                                                                 // calulcated value
```

The version above could be merged to the single `collect(..)` method:

```
Map<String, Double> finalResult = inputMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
         Entry::getKey,                        // keeps the same key
         entry -> entry.getValue()
                       .stream()               // List<String> -> Stream<String>
                                               // then Stream<String> -> Stream<Double>
                       .mapToDouble(string -> computeScore(string)) 
                       .sum()));               // and summed
```

The key parts:

- [`collect(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) performs a reduction on the elements using a certain strategy with a [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html).
- `Entry::getKey` is a shortcut for `entry -> entry.getKey`. A function for mapping the key.
- `entry -> entry.getValue().stream()` returns the `Stream<String>`
- [`mapToDouble(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) returns the DoubleStream. This has an aggregating operation [`sum(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#sum--) which sums the elements - together creates a new value for the Map.

Comment: Seems like it should work but a little messy. Can we use summingDouble to simplify this?

Comment: I have reformated it, provided the alternative solution and described it in detail.

Comment: I'd avoid the first approach as it unnecessarily creates AbstractMap.SimpleEntry objects. but the second one is good :) .

Comment: @Aominè: Thank you :) I thought first of the first snippet and finally, I converged into the second snippet in 2-3 steps (I learn Stream-API as well). I decided to keep either the first one to compare the solutions and differ from the other answer by providing an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you use the stream-based or the loop-based solution, it would be beneficial and add some clarity and structure to extract the inner loop into a method:

```
private double computeScore(Collection<String> strings) 
{
    return strings.stream().mapToDouble(this::computeScore).sum();
}
```

Of course, this could also be implemented using a loop, but ... that's exactly the point: This method can now be called, either in the outer loop, or on the values of a stream of map entries.

The outer loop or stream could also be pulled into a method. In the example below, I generalized this a bit: The type of the keys of the map does not matter. Neither does whether the values are `List` or `Collection` instances.

As an alternative to the currently accepted answer, the stream-based solution here does not fill a new map that is created manually. Instead, it uses a `Collector`.

(This is similar to other answers, but I think that the extracted `computeScore` method greatly simplifies the otherwise rather ugly lambdas that are necessary for the nested streams)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ToStreamOrNotToStream
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ToStreamOrNotToStream t = new ToStreamOrNotToStream();

        Map<String, List<String>> inputMap =
            new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        inputMap.put("A", Arrays.asList("1.0", "2.0", "3.0"));
        inputMap.put("B", Arrays.asList("2.0", "3.0", "4.0"));
        inputMap.put("C", Arrays.asList("3.0", "4.0", "5.0"));

        System.out.println("Result A: " + t.computeA(inputMap));
        System.out.println("Result B: " + t.computeB(inputMap));
    }

    private <T> Map<T, Double> computeA(
        Map<T, ? extends Collection<String>> inputMap)
    {
        Map<T, Double> finalResult = new HashMap<>();
        for (Entry<T, ? extends Collection<String>> entry : inputMap.entrySet())
        {
            double score = computeScore(entry.getValue());
            finalResult.put(entry.getKey(), score);
        }
        return finalResult;
    }

    private <T> Map<T, Double> computeB(
        Map<T, ? extends Collection<String>> inputMap)
    {
        return inputMap.entrySet().stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> computeScore(e.getValue()))); 
    }

    private double computeScore(Collection<String> strings) 
    {
        return strings.stream().mapToDouble(this::computeScore).sum();
    }

    private double computeScore(String a)
    {
        return Double.parseDouble(a);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it somewhat shorter:

```
value = startDates.entrySet().stream().mapToDouble(Entry::getValue).sum();
```